# Perform NGram on Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm using Spark 2.3.1, I have Spark DataFrame like this

```
+----------+
|    values|
+----------+
|embodiment|
|   present|
| invention|
|   include|
|   pairing|
|       two|
|  wireless|
|    device|
|   placing|
|     least|
|       one|
|       two|
+----------+
```

I want to perform a Spark ml n-Gram feature like this.

```
bigram = NGram(n=2, inputCol="values", outputCol="bigrams")

bigramDataFrame = bigram.transform(tokenized_df)
```

Following Error occurred on this line **bigramDataFrame = bigram.transform(tokenized_df)**

> pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'requirement failed: Input type must be ArrayType(StringType) but got StringType.'

So I changed my code

```
df_new = tokenized_df.withColumn("testing", array(tokenized_df["values"]))

bigram = NGram(n=2, inputCol="values", outputCol="bigrams")

bigramDataFrame = bigram.transform(df_new)

bigramDataFrame.show()
```

So I got my final Data Frame as Follow

```
+----------+------------+-------+
|    values|     testing|bigrams|
+----------+------------+-------+
|embodiment|[embodiment]|     []|
|   present|   [present]|     []|
| invention| [invention]|     []|
|   include|   [include]|     []|
|   pairing|   [pairing]|     []|
|       two|       [two]|     []|
|  wireless|  [wireless]|     []|
|    device|    [device]|     []|
|   placing|   [placing]|     []|
|     least|     [least]|     []|
|       one|       [one]|     []|
|       two|       [two]|     []|
+----------+------------+-------+
```

Why my bigram column value is empty.

I want my output for bigram column as follow

```
+----------+
|   bigrams|
+--------------------+
|embodiment present  |
|present invention   |
|invention include   |
|include pairing     |
|pairing two         |
|two wireless        |
|wireless device     |
|device placing      |
|placing least       |
|least one           |
|one two             |
+--------------------+
```

Comment: do you want something like: `df.select(F.concat_ws(" ",F.col("values"),F.lead("values").over(Window.orderBy(F.lit(None))))).show()` ?

Comment: @anky Your suggestion is right, can you please explain this as the answer to this post, and please suggest what I have to do to concrete three or four rows as well. I've tried myself, but it doesn't worked. Do you have any idea why pyspark ml lib feature of n-gram not working (While I ran the same code in HDP Sandbox it's work as expected same spark version) btw I'm running spark on local using spark-submit command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bi-gram column value is empty because there are no bi-grams in each row of your 'values' column.

If your values in input data frame look like:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|values                                      |
+--------------------------------------------+
|embodiment present invention include pairing|
|two wireless device placing                 |
|least one two                               |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Then you can get the output in bi-grams as below:

```
+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|values                                      |testing                                           |ngrams                                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|embodiment present invention include pairing|[embodiment, present, invention, include, pairing]|[embodiment present, present invention, invention include, include pairing]|
|two wireless device placing                 |[two, wireless, device, placing]                  |[two wireless, wireless device, device placing]                            |
|least one two                               |[least, one, two]                                 |[least one, one two]                                                       |
+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The scala spark code to do this is:

```
val df_new = df.withColumn("testing", split(df("values")," "))
val ngram = new NGram().setN(2).setInputCol("testing").setOutputCol("ngrams")
val ngramDataFrame = ngram.transform(df_new)
```

> A bi-gram is a sequence of two adjacent elements from a string of
> tokens, which are typically letters, syllables, or words.

But in your input data frame, you have only one token in each row, hence you are not getting any bi-grams out of it.

So, for your question, you can do something like this:

```
Input: df1
+----------+
|values    |
+----------+
|embodiment|
|present   |
|invention |
|include   |
|pairing   |
|two       |
|wireless  |
|devic     |
|placing   |
|least     |
|one       |
|two       |
+----------+

Output: ngramDataFrameInRows
+------------------+
|ngrams            |
+------------------+
|embodiment present|
|present invention |
|invention include |
|include pairing   |
|pairing two       |
|two wireless      |
|wireless devic    |
|devic placing     |
|placing least     |
|least one         |
|one two           |
+------------------+
```

Spark scala code:

```
val df_new=df1.agg(collect_list("values").alias("testing"))
val ngram = new NGram().setN(2).setInputCol("testing").setOutputCol("ngrams")
val ngramDataFrame = ngram.transform(df_new)
val ngramDataFrameInRows=ngramDataFrame.select(explode(col("ngrams")).alias("ngrams"))
```